# Migrating maven-shade-plugin rules to bazel

Tags: bazel

I am currently investigating bazel as a tool to speed up java builds. I have a somewhat complex build to handle, including shading of many libs.

This shading is performed today using `maven-shade-plugin`. I could not find a bazel equivalent.

The solution should be able to:

- aggregate multiple input jars
- filter in/out files
- specify which artifacts to include
- parameter relocations (!)
- propose a mechanism equivalent to resource transformers https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/resource-transformers.html

If this is out of reach, I would be very interested in some generic way to specify some input, output and "something" to lauch to produce the later from the former.

Comment: have a look at [https://github.com/google/bazel-common/tree/master/tools/jarjar] and ex. [https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/dagger2/+/refs/heads/master/BUILD#52]

Answer (score 1):

Any java_bin has an implicit _deploy.jar that contains all classes and is similar to the shaded jar:

> name_deploy.jar: A Java archive suitable for deployment (only built if explicitly requested)
>    The deploy jar contains all the classes that would be found by a classloader that searched the classpath from the binary's wrapper script from beginning to end.

https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/java.html#java_binary_implicit_outputs

But I don't think bazel provides any of the other features that you are requesting.